# Difference between Anderson localization and weak localization

Tags: disorder, anderson-localization

I have read that weak localization is a precursor to Anderson localization. Weak localization happens due to the constructive interference between paths that loop around in opposite direction, on account of guaranteed identity of phases accumulated in time reversed paths. This leads to a slightly higher than expected probability for the particle to stay back as opposed to move to a different location.

What new thing happens in Anderson localization which makes it different from weak localization ?